# Kubenetes: Error from server: the server does not allow access to the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am following the [hellonode](http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/) tutorial, deploying to Google Container Engine, but running into the error below:

```
kubectl run simple-gke-server --image=us.gcr.io/cloud-assets-henry/simple-gke-server:v1 --port=8888

Error from server: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (post replicationcontrollers)
```

Even though I am able to get the credential

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials simplecluster
```

I get this problem, even when trying to get version info.

```
kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.0", GitCommit:"a16c0a7f71a6f93c7e0f222d961f4675cd97a46b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-09-26T18:16:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}

Couldn't read server version from server: the server does not allow access to the requested resource
```

I did have to update my kubectl to 1.4.0, which matches the version of my cluster.

I have also initialized by gcloud with a config, and also did auth login.

Is there anything else that I can do?

Answer (score 17):

kubectl uses [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) for authenticating to GKE clusters. It is possible that your Application Default Credentials are configured for a different user than your gcloud credentials if you have previously configured ADC.

Try running `gcloud auth application-default login`, and make sure that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable isn't pointing somewhere unexpected.

Comment: Yes, that worked, it was indeed I had GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to something else.  Thank you!

Comment: After doing the above, I also needed to rerun the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` command but everything worked fine afterwards

Comment: after login using new account, better to open a new shell to avoid problem above.

Comment: @HenryChang If you consider your question resolved, please consider accepting the answer by checking the tick on the left-side of the answer.

Comment: @ken opening a new shell didn't help. I had to run 'gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-name'